# Java inserting a value in file input

Tags: java, image, file, input, web

I have a few images with the names "Hoofdfoto.jpg", "foto2.jpg","foto3.jpg","foto4.jpg","foto5.jpg"

I want to automatically using java add them to a website with this source code : http://pastebin.com/MPatCqk9

If you press ctrl+F and type in "Foto 2" you see that it's a file inputbox, any idea how to make java put it in there?

Comment: So you want to upload a file in a Java Web application?

Comment: Retagging from java to javascript

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  No , the site with the sourcecode is an existing site, I'm making a bot to load in articles into the website, all I need left is the images.

For an idea how the bot works :
http://pastebin.com/vec00yDB

Please don't retag it,I am talking about java, not javascript !

Comment: @vikingsteve this is not a JavaScript question